# Invalid command error 'mkdir' while excuting #expect script

Tags: linux, shell

The expect script returning invalid command while I trying to create a folder after login to server via ssh

This is the below error I got

```
invalid command name "mkdir"
    while executing
"mkdir new"
   (file "./connecttotravalour.exp" line 8)
```

And the code on my expect script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
#connect to travalour host

spawn ssh travalour@travalour.local
expect "password"
send "P@ssw0rd\r"
interact
mkdir new
```

Comment: Try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/703754/how-to-do-more-with-an-expect-script-than-just-a-log-in

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer form [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703754/how-to-do-more-with-an-expect-script-than-just-a-log-in) for similar question

The main thrust of expect programming is send and expect pairs: you send some text to the spawned process and expect a response. In this case, you send the mkdir command, and expect to see your prompt to know that the command has completed. Prompts are best matched as regular expressions to match the end of it. Since prompts are so configurable, you might want to edit the prompt expression: this one matches a literal dollar sign and a space at the end of the string.

```
#!/bin/bash
#connect to travalour host

spawn ssh travalour@travalour.local
expect "password"
send "P@ssw0rd\r"
set prompt_re {\$ $}
expect -re $prompt_re
send "mkdir -p new"
expect -re $prompt_re
interact
```

Comment: Your code works parshually, Now I connected to my server and the command is now show on terminal like
'travalour@TRAVALOUR-SVR:~$ mkdir -p new'

When I press enter the new directory created, I need to do it also via shell ..